# Delete item in Arraylist in RecyclerView within Adapter

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble to delete one item in my Arraylist from `Firebase` Database using `RecyclerView`. There is an `AlertDialog` which I can see when I'm clicking on it, but it doesn't delete the Item. I think the problem is, that I cannot get the `postID` correctly. But I tried it in many ways, and within the database Reference I wasn't able to do it right.

This is where I add the Post to the database:

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Posts")
val postId = ref.push().key
```

And here you can see my `PostsAdapter`

```
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.posts_layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mPosts.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        FirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        val posts = mPosts[position]

        holder.title.text = posts.getTitle()
        holder.content.text = posts.getContent()
        holder.deletePost.text = posts.getPostId()

        ownerInfo(holder.name, posts.getOwner())
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(@NonNull itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),
        View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
            val intent = Intent(itemView.context, DeletePostActivity::class.java)
            // here pass id through intent
            intent.putExtra("postId", R.id.deletePost)
            itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
        }

        var title: TextView
        var content: TextView
        var owner: TextView
        var name: TextView
        var deletePost: Button


        init{
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_title)
            content = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_content)
            owner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_owner)
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_owner)
            deletePost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_delete)

            deletePost.setOnClickListener{
                AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
                    .setTitle("Löschen")
                    .setMessage("Wollen Sie diesen Post wirklich löschen?")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ja") { dialog, which ->
                        notifyItemRemoved(adapterPosition)
                        notifyItemRangeChanged(adapterPosition, mPosts.size)

                        val postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Posts").child("postID")

                        postsRef.child("postID").removeValue()

                    }
                    .create()
                    .show()
            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: For every item are you navigate to another activity to delete it?
If yes you should get back the string from intent, i don't see it, did you just forgot copy here that part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are not passing any `postID` to delete. Check below

Instead of

```
val postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Posts").child("postID")
postsRef.child("postID").removeValue()
```

use

```
val postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Posts").child(deletePost.text)
postsRef.removeValue()
```

Comment: I was thinking the same, but he is sending to another activity that value, probably he needs getString()